# How can I define the elements of a zeros representation equal to a value?

Tags: python

In the following code I want to replace the elements I want with the arrival_time value

```
 for lamda in lam_vec:
t = 0
q = 0
i = 1
j = 0
k = 0
show = np.zeros((2,i))
AR = np.zeros((1,j))
DE = np.zeros((1,k))
delay = np.zeros(())
queui = np.zeros((1,i))
arrival_time = 0 + np.random.exponential(1 / lamda)
j = j + 1
AR(1,j) = arrival_time
t = arrival_time
```

how can I do?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output to test against? It's not exactly clear what the goal is here; is `j` being incremented in a loop?

Comment: please provide full or sample script and output error

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can use empty array and use append()

```
AR=[]
for lamba in lam_vec:
  if i==0:
    AR.append(0)
  else:
    AR.append(int(temp - temp%1))
```